# Do the subspaces of a vector space form a distributive lattice?

Tags: vector-spaces, lattice-orders

Ordered by inclusion. There is a least element $\{0\}$ and a greatest element $V$. Also for two subspaces $V_1,V_2$ we have $V_1\land V_2 = V_1 \cap V_2$. But what is $V_1\lor V_2$? The union of two subspaces need not be a subspace, right?

/edit: Okay I get that it's a lattice if you take intersection and sum. Now [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Linear_subspace&oldid=696763359) this lattice is distributive. But what if I have three different 1-dimensional subspaces $A, B, C$ of $\mathbb R^2$, then
$$A\cap (B+C) = A \neq \{0\} = (A\cap B)+(A\cap C)$$
Am I wrong?

Comment: No, but the span $V_1 + V_2$ of two subspaces is a subspace.

Comment: But do we have $V_1\lor V_2 = V_1 + V_2$ ie is it really the _least_ subspace that contains both $V_1$ and $V_2$?

Comment: Never mind, I get that. But then how is the lattice distributive? See edit above.

Comment: Why are you assuming $A \cap (B+C) = A$ and $(A \cap B) + (A \cap C) = {0}$?

Comment: $A,B,C$ are different 1-dimensional subspaces. Doesn't that imply $A+B = \mathbb R^2$ and $A\cap B = \{0\}$?

Comment: You're right. This lattice is not distributive in general, but it is modular.

Comment: So the Wikipedia article is just wrong? Should we change it to modular?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. And after that there are lines saying that this lattice can be viewed as a Boolean algebra (with complements being orthogonal complements). This is also false, since this lattice is not distributive. We can only say that it is a complemented modular lattice.

Comment: What a very egregious error...